# How to make independent vectors appear alongside one another within a group?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning ggplot.  I have made a plot I'm almost happy with, and there is one detail to fix.

My data is here:

```
gIN <- c("A_1","A_2","A_3","A_4","B_1","B_2","B_3","B_4","B_5","C_1","C_2","C_3")
bc <- c(1219.79, 1486.84, 1255.80, 941.87, 588.19, 304.02, 279.71, 373.40, 179.89, 385.02, 218.76, 423.33)
bc2 <- c(319.79, 186.84, 125.80, 94.87, 1008.19, 314.02, 500.71, 600.40, 900.89, 38.02, 1000.76, 500.33)
group <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C")

ex <- data.frame("gIN" = gIN, "bc" = bc, "bc2"=bc2, "group" = group)
```

I am attempting to show vectors bc and bc2 alongside one another, but they are superimposed in the way I constructed the command, here:

```
ggplot(data=ex) + facet_grid(. ~group, scales="free") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=group, y=bc,group=group,colour="bc")) + geom_point(aes(x=group, y=bc,colour="bc")) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=group, y=bc2,group=group,colour="bc2")) + geom_point(aes(x=group, y=bc2,colour="bc2"))
```

Plot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/od6xVRT.png]

As you can see, group A looks OK because the blue and red lines are separate, but when the values overlap (like in group B and C), it becomes impossible to see the data clearly.

Does anyone know how to change the command to put each vector side-by-side instead of superimposed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution that involves rearranging your data a bit with `melt()` and using a categorical x-axis to separate your 'bc' and 'bc2' data types. Another benefit is that the plotting code itself is simpler to write.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

mdat = melt(ex, id.vars=c("gIN", "group"), value.vars=c("bc", "bc2"))

head(mdat)
#   gIN group variable   value
# 1 A_1     A       bc 1219.79
# 2 A_2     A       bc 1486.84
# 3 A_3     A       bc 1255.80
# 4 A_4     A       bc  941.87
# 5 B_1     B       bc  588.19
# 6 B_2     B       bc  304.02


p = ggplot(mdat, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() + 
    facet_grid(. ~ group)
```

[image]